# PubNub throwing "CryptographicException:Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

Tags: c#, pubnub, ringcentral

I'm trying to subscribe to a RingCentral service to get notified on new phone calls. I'm using the PubNub C# Nuget package. The notification subscription works fine, and then I connect to PubNub using the following:

```
var pn = new Pubnub("", "sub-c-...", "sec-c-ZDNlYjY0OWMtGHFmOC00OTg2LWJjMTMtYjBkMzgzOWRmMzUz", "SJG...==", false);
pn.Subscribe<string>("412276449514272_46d8dac5", u => Debug.WriteLine("u:" + u), c => Debug.WriteLine("c:" + c), e => Debug.WriteLine("e:" + e));
```

However when a phone call is made, Pubnub sends my code a notification, but the Pubnub code crashes with "CryptographicException:Padding is invalid and cannot be removed". Does anyone have any experience with this?

The cipher key `SJG...==` seems like it's base64, but decoding it to a string doesn't work (just produces question marks with both ASCII and UTF8), so I'm assuming that this is the actual cipher key.

Comment: Not sure of the issue but you now need to regen your secret key and change your crypto key because you have exposed it to the world. I removed it but a little late now. Can you post this issue to support@pubnub.com and we'll deal with this in private and post back any solutions without any sensitive data exposed? And there is no need to send your secret-key to us either because we have it in your account. Just send your sub-key.

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks but no fear - I had adjusted them first.

Comment: Good to know. Did you submit to support yet?

Comment: @CraigConover Yes, case #13877, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

RingCentral API is using 128bit AES with ECB mode and standard PKCS7 padding. Keys and ciphers are Base64 encoded.

RingCentral encryption is different from what Pubnub has, so you should not provide an encryption key to PubNub client. Instead, you should decode PubNub messages by hand using above mentioned settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try RingCentral SDK 1.0.0. In 1.0.0 BouncyCastle is used to do decryption of message. And here is some code for your reference:

```
private object Decrypt(string dataString)
{
   var key = Convert.FromBase64String(subscriptionInfo.DeliveryMode.EncryptionKey);
   var keyParameter = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", key);
   var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
   cipher.Init(false, keyParameter);

   var data = Convert.FromBase64String(dataString);
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data, false);
   var cipherStream = new CipherStream(memoryStream, cipher, null);

   var bufferSize = 1024;
   var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
   var length = 0;
   var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
   while ((length = cipherStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
   {
       resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
   }
   var resultBytes = resultStream.ToArray();
   var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes, 0, resultBytes.Length);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
}
```

The decryption is taken care for you automatically so you don't need to do it yourself.